# Are questions about where certain apps store their data permitted?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm looking for the data files of one of the apps I use on my phone.

It occurred to me that such questions might not be allowed on the site from my experience of the varying rules from one SE site to another.

Should I go ahead and ask or would that not fall within the scope of the site?

Comment: First I'd say you should go ahead and use the site search. That question has already be answered more than once – and usually is not specific to a single app. There are always the same 2-3 locations, the only specific part of the path being the app's package name :)

Comment: To add to what Izzy said, there's no problem in asking about the data quirks of a particular app… if knowing them may be of use to end-users, which is what this site is geared towards.

Comment: I used the site but it doesn't always find what you're looking for (-: